# Write file xlsx in R without using Java

Tags: r, xlsx, openxlsx, writexl

wight now I'having an issue with R. I could not use library openxlsx in my PC. When I try to import, these errors show me that:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘openxlsx’:
 object ‘zipr’ is not exported by 'namespace:zip'
```

Any one suggest me some different method to save file in xlsx format. I tried `writexl` package, however I don't know how to save file in seperate worksheets, the description of the function write_xlsx in this package only show me this:

```
write_xlsx(
  x,
  path = tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx"),
  col_names = TRUE,
  format_headers = TRUE
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you use the [`WriteXLS`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/WriteXLS/versions/5.0.0/topics/WriteXLS) package?

```
WriteXLS(x, ExcelFileName = paste0(tempfile, ".xlsx"), SheetNames = NULL, row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)
```

Edit:
If you're trying to save data to different sheets, turn your data into a list:

```
mySheets = c("data1", "data2")
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you would like to continue using openxlsx library in order to save in xlsx format and with different worksheets, you can solve the namespace error by upgrading the zip package to latest version v2.1.0, same issue as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62598883/how-to-fix-namespace-error-when-running-zip/63755257#63755257). The zip package is a dependency of openxlsx.

Comment: @help-info.de I'm not sure I understand. Is this answer not different from the other answer? Or are you saying that one should not answer Questions that already has an accepted Answer?

Comment: @Scrattle - my comment ist a hint only for reading the question carefully. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful.

Comment: @help-info.de Thank you for your suggestions and comments. I have edited the reply so as to clarify better. I believe the answer gives the user and additional way of solving the problem, namely saving to an xlsx file with different worksheets.